# How to play a movie with alpha channel on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, video, alpha

I'm trying to load and view a video with an alpha channel in Qt. The video was encoded using Quicktime Animation set to RGB + Alpha and Millions of Colors+. I'm sure the video has transparency working as I loaded it into After Effects and checked.

I tried using the Phonon module with no success. The video loads alright but without the alpha channel, it just shows a black background. I tried setting WA_TranslucentBackground attribute but that didn't work either. GIF is not an option since the graphics are quite complex.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure but i think there is no easy way to do this. What about doing a screenshot and set it as background of the movie. So it looks like it would be transparent.

Comment: @riv333 We used that technique in another opportunity, however, this time the background is not static. I'm thinking of reading a video using ffmpeg and rendering it in a QGLWidget. Do you think this could be a good idea?

Comment: If the video does not contain audio, perhaps you can pre-extract frames as independent images using ffmpeg, then write a custom player to render the individual images onto a QLabel, preserving the alpha?

Comment: Yeah, I think that will be the only approach Jim. But that isn't quite simple of implementing, at last not like having a widget like phonon already supporting it. That's the way I will do it and as soon as I have a working code, I will post here a minimal example.

Comment: im not sure quicktime does this, I've always loaded into after effects to check this..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible (don't know the export options for After Effects) but did you try converting the movie to the MNG format? Then you can load it with QMovie, and it supports alpha channel (may be quite heavy in size, though).

Maybe this link will help: http://www.libpng.org/pub/mng/mngapcv.html

Comment: QMovie don't support alpha channel, as far as I know.